# Why can't I connect my phone to my laptop in a public Wi-Fi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, ip

I'm developing an app/server. The server is running locally on my laptop.
At home I look at network utility (Im on OS X) which gives my laptop's local ip address. On my phone I tell the app to connect to that ip for testing. **This works fine.** Usually addresses are 192.168.0.40 or something like this.

But today Im in a (big) public library, with **lots of people** using the free Wi-Fi. The above process to connect doesn't work; My computer's local ip looks more complicated (10.177.53.216). Is there a way to connect the devices?

Comment: That "local IP" is actually a WAN IP; did you mean "**10**.177.53.216"?

Comment: Because the library isn't assigning a public ip address to your laptop.  You won't be able to connect to your laptop from you phone while your at the library.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 yes I wanted to obfuscate it... not very smart from me :)

Comment: @Thomas LAN IPs (10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16) are IPs used in private networks; those are assigned at will by the router of your network and doesn't mean anything outside the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely because AP Isolation is on; this prevents clients connected to the same wireless network from communicating to each other as a security measure. This is usually turned on in public networks so hackers can't just go around the network scanning for vulnerabilities in other people's devices.

I would suggest setting up your own Wi-Fi hotspot instead of relying on the public Wi-Fi network if you want devices to be able to talk to each other over LAN.